# How to select only 20 checkbox rows in aggrid and disable other checkbox once that number is met

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a checkbox with the following col def

> {
> headerName: "",
> checkboxSelection: true,
> headerCheckboxSelection: true,
> cellEditorParams: {
> isError: false,
> errorRows: [],
> maxlength: 4
> },
> valueGetter: function (params) {
> return "";
> },
> }

giving the following Output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow85L.png)

Now i have to select only 20 checkbox with the header checkbox and other checkbox should disable, and
if user selects checkboxes one by once after 20 checkbox are selected , the other rows with checkboxshould disable

I tried getting the row index and count of the rows selected and add showDisabledCheckboxes: true,
to those rows, but it does not work